Cognos analytics pdf export charts not showing
I'm trying to export a 2 tab dashboard to pdf. Some of my charts are showing up in the pdf and some are not. Specifically my column, bar and column/line charts are not showing. No problem with heatmap or treemap.
It says 'We can't load this visualization'. I don't know what to do to solve this.
